# Is this phrase or clause a clause?

Tags: syntax, parts-of-speech, word-order, words, clauses

Is "lefty loosey, righty tighty" a clause?

Or what is "lefty loosey, righty tighty"?

Or what part of speech is "lefty loosey, righty tighty"?

Or what part of speech is each word in "lefty loosey, righty tighty"?

Why did someone vote this question down or show that this question is bad?

If it's "bad", can you show why you vote it down or why it is "bad" instead of just voting it down?

Comment: It's a mnemonic motto, like _Spring forward, Fall back_. When we put together words to help us remember, they don't have to follow the same rules as ordinary talk. It's not part of an English sentence and thus has little or no grammar; in any event it's got no verb and no subject, so it's certainly not a clause.

Comment: I think I've known or seen that it's a mnemonic but I think I was thinking or wondering if it is a phrase or a clause or a set phrase or a part of speech or I was thinking what it might be.

Answer (score 1):

One explanation is all of the words in the mnemonic are adjectives, then this would be adjective phrases and certainly not a clause.

But my first instinct was to interpret this as the following:

- The words "lefty" and "righty" are diminutive nouns;
- The words "loosey" and "tighty" are adjectives;
- Since English *usually* tends to have an Adjective-Noun order, these are probably not just noun phrases;
- These could be two clauses, with zero copula/linking verb... which is not super usual for Standard English, but could still be permissible: lefty (is) loosey, righty (is) tighty.

This is my analysis of this, but it's the first time I see this mnemonic.

Comment: I was also thinking that "lefty loosey, righty tighty" might be or show "when it goes lefty, it gets loosey and when it goes righty, it gets tighty" or "when it goes to lefty, it gets loosey and when it goes to righty, it gets tighty". What might you think?

Comment: Do you think "lefty loosey, righty tighty" might be a clause, a phrase, a set phrase, an expression, a minor sentence, a clipped clause or a clause clipping?

Comment: What might you think? Or what might you think "lefty loosey, righty tighty" is?

Comment: The phonology is overwhelming. _Righty_ and _tighty_ rhyme, whereas _lefty_ and _loosy_ share assonance and final syllable, though they don't rhyme. They're just different enough to indicate a difference (the point of the mnemonic) and just similar enough to memorize effortlessly.